# Assembly Function calling x64 VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 64-bit, inline-assembly

So I am writing a wrapper for main and still provide a main like functionality, so user can define int main() or int main(argc, argv) and both works fine. I am able to do that for some compilers with inline assembly with pushing argc & argv onto stack before calling the user's main. However for x64 VC++, there is no inline assembly, so any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What? How can you "wrap" `main`? Calling the user's main? :S

Comment: Why does the wrapper need to be written in assembly? Just write the wrapper in C and let the compiler do the work. especially since the x64 calling convention does not pass parameters on the stack. It also requires unwind codes.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: At least one major compiler (gcc) defines a wrapping function which calls your `main` (see e.g. http://learningpearls.blogspot.de/2011/02/start-function-inside-c.html). This can be useful stuff to know when squeezing the last bytes out of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two obvious choices: either write your code in assembly language, contained in an assembly language file, or else write your code in C++ without any inline assembly:

```
void my_entry_point() { 
     int argc = foo();
     int argv = bar();
     int ret = main(argc, argv);
     exit_to_os(ret);
}
```

Comment: doh so engrossed in inline being not allowed, that i forgot a plain old ASM hah